# Нерабочие элементы после добавления Layout vs конфликт, используя binding

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, kotlin, android-fragment

Создал 2 приложения: 1ое(Основное) - в котором есть нижнее меню из 3-х элементов. Каждый отдельный элемент меню - фрагмент, на котором отображает отличная от другого информация. Во 2ом приложении(созданный фрагмент) - то что будет отображаться на отдельном фрагменте из меню(показалось что проще сделать каждый фрагмент отдельно, протестировать его, а потом добавить в основное приложение). Возникла проблема переноса созданного фрагмента в основную часть. Добавленный элемент отображается правильно, но кнопки не функционируют(начиная с кнопки `Add`, добавляющей `View`, заканчивая последней). Насколько понял, проблема в отображаемом `layout` в `MainActivity.kt`, используя `binding`, но не могу понять как решить это.

**Структура проекта.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.sapr_2

import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.sapr_2.Classes.Rod
import com.example.sapr_2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.example.sapr_2.databinding.FragmentPreprocessorBinding // фрагмент на котором добавляются стержни


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var _bindingPreprocessor: FragmentPreprocessorBinding? = null // биндинг к 1 фрагменту меню
private val bindingPreprocessor get() = _bindingPreprocessor!!

private var _bindingActivityMain: ActivityMainBinding? = null
private val bindingActivityMain get() = _bindingActivityMain!!

private var rodsList = ArrayList<Rod>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    _bindingPreprocessor = FragmentPreprocessorBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.container_fragment)
    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)


    //setContentView(bindingPreprocessor.root)

    bindingPreprocessor.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
        addNewView()
    }

    bindingPreprocessor.buttonRemove.setOnClickListener {
        removeLastView()
    }

    bindingPreprocessor.buttonSubmitList.setOnClickListener {
        saveData()
    }

    bindingPreprocessor.buttonShowList.setOnClickListener {
        showData() //вывод введённых данных через Toast.makeText()
    }
    Log.d("SaprLog", "OnCreate")
}


private fun addNewView() {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row_add_rod, null)
    bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.addView(inflater, bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.childCount)
}

private fun removeLastView() {
   val view = bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.childCount-1)
   bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.removeView(view)
}


private fun saveData() {
   rodsList.clear()

   val count = bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.childCount // он считает кол-во элементов в контейнере
   var v: View?

   for (i in 0 until count) {
       v = bindingPreprocessor.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i)

       val rodLength: EditText? = v.findViewById(R.id.length_rod)
       val rodb: EditText? = v.findViewById(R.id.b_rod)
       val rodE: EditText? = v.findViewById(R.id.E_rod)
       val rodSigma: EditText? = v.findViewById(R.id.Sigma_rod)

       val rod= Rod()
       rod.L = rodLength?.text.toString().toInt()  //--добавление 1 переменной L
       rod.b = rodb?.text.toString().toDouble()  //--добавление 2 переменной b
       rod.E = rodE?.text.toString().toDouble()  //--добавление 3 переменной Е
       rod.Sigma = rodSigma?.text.toString().toDouble()  //--добавление 4 переменной Sigma

       rodsList.add(rod)
   }
}
```

Я добавил реализацию функций `addNewView()`, `removeLastView()` и `saveData()`, чтобы показать, что они работают, получая данные из Layout `fragment_preprocessor.xml` от `bindingPreprocessor`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если раскомментировать строку `//setContentView(bindingPreprocessor.root)`, то выведется рабочий `Layout`(кнопки функционируют), но без нижнего меню, то есть сменить фрагмент невозможно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:id="@+id/container_fragment"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**fragment_preprocessor.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.Preprocessor">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="@string/rods_input"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_24"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/remove"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/submit_list"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_show_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/show_list_data"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**navigation.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/preprocessor">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/postprocessor"
        android:name="com.example.sapr_2.fragments.Postprocessor"
        android:label="fragment_postprocessor"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_postprocessor" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/processor"
        android:name="com.example.sapr_2.fragments.Processor"
        android:label="fragment_processor"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_processor" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/preprocessor"
        android:name="com.example.sapr_2.fragments.Preprocessor"
        android:label="fragment_preprocessor"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_preprocessor" />

</navigation>
```